# Python variables stored in text files not working, but should be

Tags: python, file, text, logical-operators

I've settled on a text-file based save system for my game, storing the values of required variables with keywords - for example, the password that tells the game which chapter to play. However, it appears to be malfunctioning, and I can't see why.

Before starting the game, we have:

```
if not os.file.isfile('TSGsave{0}.txt'.format(name)):
    TSGsave=open('TSGsave{0}.txt'.format(name),'wt')
    TSGsave.write('\nw5CT$n<jfW=-#J%4Ya5@@')
    TSGsave.close()
```

(the keyword used is a bunch of jibberish so that the user can't change it knowing what's going to happen). This adds `w5CT$n<jfW=-#J%4Ya5@@` to the text file. We then have:

```
for i in range (len(lines)):
    if 'w5CT$n<jfW' in lines[i]:
        findpass=lines[i]
        for i in range (len(findpass)):
            if findpass[i]=='=':
                cutfrom=i+1
                password=findpass[cutfrom:len(findpass)]
```

to retrieve the variable (which can change, so it can't be written in as definite value). I know it works, because I added `print (password)` to the code and it returned `-#J%4Ya5@@`. Then to start the corresponding chapter, the code is:

```
if password=='-#J%4Ya5@@':
```

but it isn't starting the indented block. In the shell, the program ends and goes back to the `>>>` line.

If there is a way to fix this code, great - but another code to do the same thing would work just as well.

Comment: Just a small side note. Instead of an external .txt file you could use a external py file in which you store that data. Then all you have to do is import that file into your game and you will have access variables, methods, etc.

Comment: Why not just pickle/jsonify an object containing all your data? If you don't want it to be too easy for users to tamper with the data, simply obfuscate it (even though that's somewhat pointless if the python sourcecode is included).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lines contain newlines, and these are being included. Strip these from the line:

```
findpass = lines[i].rstrip('\n')
```

Printing a value with a newline in it will simply add an extra black line after the `print`. Always use the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) to produce a Python representation of strings to see such characters:

```
>>> print '-#J%4Ya5@@\n'
-#J%4Ya5@@

>>> print repr('-#J%4Ya5@@\n')
'-#J%4Ya5@@\n'
```

Your parsing code is overly complicated; you can use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) or [`str.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to split your password from the line instead. You should just loop over the `lines` list *directly* rather than produce indices with `range()`:

```
for line in lines:
    if 'w5CT$n<jfW' in line:
        password = line.partition('=')[2].rstrip('\n')
```